# Absolute path using fs in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am trying to pipe an `http audio stream` from my `nodejs` server:

```
var streamPath = 'http://127.0.0.1:1485/mystream.mp3';
var stat = fs.statSync(streamPath);
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg','Content-Length': stat.size});
fs.createReadStream(streamPath).pipe(response);
```

The problem is that `fs` doesn't like the absolute path and I get the following error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\myserver\http:\127.0.0.1:1485\mystream.mp3'

I can't find a way to use the `absolute path`. Is this even possible using `fs`?

Comment: var path = require('path'); var strPath = path.join(__dirname, '/publiuc/audio/mystream.mp3'); Maybe like this?

Comment: `fs` is meant to be used for the _local_ filesystem and not for remote resources. Use `http` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'http://127.0.0.1:1485/mystream.mp3'` is not an absolute path, it's a URL.

Absolute paths are something like `/home/x/dir/file.txt` on your filesystem.

If you want to get a stream from a URL then you need to use `http` or `request`. Or you need to use a path on your filesystem and not a URL if you want to get a file on your filesystem without using the network.

`fs.createReadStream` can only open local file in your filesystem.

For more details, see:

- https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

To get a file over a network, see:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/request
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

Comment: var request = require('request'); request('http://127.0.0.1:1485/stream/swyh.mp3').pipe(response);

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a remote resource through `fs` - that is wrong. `fs` is meant to be used for the `Local Filesystem`. If you want to access any remote resource you have to use `http` or `https`. However if I see things correctly you are trying to access your `localhost`, which should work.

Your Application is trying to access following file: `C:\myserver\http:\127.0.0.1:1485\mystream.mp3` if you look closely that can't work. Your Path is mixed with your local path and a remote source (which is `localhost` actually). Try to fix your path, that should solve your problem. Keep in mind that `fs` will only work on your local system.

You should also think about `fs.statSync` this will block everything else until its finished.

**Docs:**

1. fs: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html
2. http: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html
3. https: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html

Regards,
Megajin